# Vector in row space and null space of a matrix is necessarily 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This fact was proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1678572/why-a-vector-in-both-the-null-space-and-row-space-has-to-be-0), but only for $$A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$$ 
Is there a proof for a matrix over a general field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ in the field of integers modulo 2. The only row of the matrix is in its null space.

Comment: Right. And also (i 1) over the complex numbers.

Comment: Yes. In general $\sum_{i} x_i^2 = 0$ does not imply $x_i = 0 \forall i$ which is used in the proof for real numbers.